# Is this pattern for handling IO exceptions in Java correct?

Tags: java, io

In the following code snippet, if ex1 is thrown, will be be caught by the second catch block, or will it be thrown back to the caller of the method?

And if it is thrown back to the caller, and then a second exception occurs in the finally block (ex2), does that mean 2 exceptions will be thrown back to the caller (ex1 and ex2)?

```
try {
  // write to file
} catch (IOException ex1) {
  throw ex1;
} finally {
  try {
    aBufferedWriter.close();
  } catch (IOException ex2) {
    throw ex2;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you just rethrow the exception then there is no point in catching it.

Comment: Why do you even catch when you throw it in your catch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of those exceptions would be thrown back to the caller... although a single exception in any particular situation. If the body of the outer try block throws and then `close` throws as well, only the second exception would be seen by the caller.

However, having a `catch` block just to rethrow is pointless. Your code would be clearer as:

```
try {
  // write to file
} finally {
  aBufferedWriter.close();
}
```

In Java 7, a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) can do that automatically:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(...)) {
    // Use the writer here
} // The writer is auto-closed here
```

That way you can *also* get at an exception on close separately from an exception in the main body, using [`Throwable.getSuppressed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getSuppressed%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the design. You can also try

```
try{
    try{
      //write to file
    }finally{
       aBufferedWriter.close();
    }
}catch(IOException e){
}
```

Also why catch the exception if you want to throw it.

Comment: I am just showing different try-catch pattern. Exception handling will obviously depend on what he intends to do with the catched Exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Q. In the following code snippet, if ex1 is thrown, will be be caught by the second catch block, or will it be thrown back to the caller of the method?

No, it won't be caught by the `catch` block inside the `finally`, provided there is no exception in the finally block and thus the exception `ex1` would be thrown back to the caller method.

---

> Q. And if it is thrown back to the caller, and then a second exception occurs in the finally block (ex2), does that mean 2 exceptions will be thrown back to the caller (ex1 and ex2)?

In this case, since a exception gets thrown in the finally block, it'll overwrite the exception thrown in the outer catch block and resulting in the exception `ex2` getting thrown back to the caller method.

Only either of the exceptions would be thrown back to the caller method for a single execution of this, not both. That being said, having a `catch` block just to throw back the exception which has been caught, is really pointless.

Answer (score 0):

**Before Java 7**, the really accurate pattern was

```
public void writeToFile(String file) throws IOException {
    IOException exception = null;
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        // TODO: write data to file
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // store exception for later rethrow
        exception = ex;
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // do NOT supress 'outer' exception:
            if (exception == null) {
                exception = ex;
            }
        }
    }

    if (exception != null) {
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Looks crazy, but this covers every possibility and circumvents exception supressed exceptions (when an exception is thrown in the `finally` statement, it supresses the 'real' exception that happened in the `try` block - if any).

But maybe - for the sake of readability - you can live with suppressed exceptions and do it like that:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
try {
    // TODO: write data to file
} finally {
    out.close(); // if an exception is thrown here, it hides the original exception
}
```

See also http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-handling-templates.html

**Since Java 7**, you can do (almost) the same with a try-with-resource statement:

```
public void writeToFile(String file) throws IOException {
    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    // TODO: write data to file
    }
}
```

Note that exceptions that are thrown when the resource is closed do NOT suppress the original exception. Instead this additional exceptions are added as 'suppressed exceptions' to the base exception. You can get them with `baseException.getSuppressed()` (Java 7 and above!).

See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html